Defining a class function for multiple classes in R
I have a class "model" and I've defined a print function for this class
model.print(object){
  print(model$beta)
}

Now say I have another class "model_2", for which I want to use the exact same print function. Is there an easier way to also define this function for this class, without separately having to write out a full model_2.print function?


It should be print.model(); 2) Though this makes a copy, maybe print.model_2 <- print.model.


You do not write which object oriented paradigma you are using (S3 or S4), but I guess it is S3. In this case, it might also be helpful that you can assign more than one class attribute to the same object (class is a character vector). That way you can do the specialization in the print.model() function by querying whether model_2 is among the the object's classes.

Why not have model_2 inherit from model?

If

beta is supposed to represent the model coefficients
we are in control of the class

then it would be easiest to just name the component coefficients rather than beta since then the coef generic can be used without defining anything since its default behavior is to extract the coefficients component.
The as.* methods defined here are just so that we can create a self contained example.  You may not need them.  Note that there is no coef.lm -- even lm relies on coef.default.  (Try methods(coef) to see what methods exist.)
# coerce to class model 
as.model <- function(x, ...) structure(x, class = c("model", "lm"))

# coerce to class model2
as.model2 <- function(x, ...) structure(x, class = c("model2", "model", "lm"))
 
obj1 <- as.model(lm(demand ~ Time, BOD))
obj2 <- as.model2(lm(demand ~ Time + 0, BOD))

coef(obj1)
## (Intercept)        Time 
##    8.521429    1.721429 

coef(obj2)
##     Time 
## 3.524038

or if you really want a print method then
format.model <- function(x, ...) format(coef(x), ...)
print.model <- function(x, ...) print(format(x), ...)
 
obj1
## (Intercept)        Time 
##    8.521429    1.721429 

obj2
##     Time 
## 3.524038

fyi, here is the source code of coef.default.
stats:::coef.default
## function (object, complete = TRUE, ...) 
## {
##     cf <- object$coefficients
##     if (complete) 
##         cf
##     else cf[!is.na(cf)]
## }
## <bytecode: 0x00000197f2b49f20>
## <environment: namespace:stats>


Maybe the following code solves your problem.
The print method for objects of class "model_2" calls the method for objects of class "model" and does nothing else so the results are nearly identical.
The difference is the class of the arguments.
In the 1st case,
attr(,"class")
[1] "model" "numeric"

in the 2nd case
attr(,"class")
[1] "model_2" "numeric"


Now a working example.
print.model <- function(x, ...) {
  message("This is 'print.model'")
  print.default(x)
}
print.model_2 <- function(x, ...) {
  print.model(x, ...)
}
as_model <- function(x) {
  class(x) <- c("model", class(x))
  x
}
as_model_2 <- function(x) {
  class(x) <- c("model_2", class(x))
  x
}

x <- as_model(1:5)
y <- as_model_2(rnorm(4))

x
#> This is 'print.model'
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "model"   "integer"
y
#> This is 'print.model'
#> [1] -0.1329577 -0.5115048 -3.1441337 -0.3179638
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "model_2" "numeric"

Created on 2024-04-26 with reprex v2.1.0
